Is it possible to completely remove previously tracked objects from Git LFS server on GitHub?
In a github repository I have the quota for Git LFS exceeded.

How to see current data/quota for Git LFS on GitHub?:
Access your organization GitHub web page > Go to your organization's Settings tab > In the left-hand menu, find the “Billing and plans”
section > In “Billing and plans” is Git LFS Data > Here we can see the
data for “Storage” and “Bandwidth”.

In fact, after checking, large files previously tracked by Git LFS and which I had removed from the workspace and index (but not completely from the history) several months ago were still present in the history. So I cleaned up the history as follows::

1 Identify large files deleted from the repository (lists the 50 largest objects -files- still present in the history, but no longer in the current repository):
git rev-list --objects --all | grep -f <(git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | sort -k3 -n | tail -50 | awk '{print$1}')

2 Delete large files from history:
The following was done for each selected file to be deleted
git filter-repo --path '<path/to/the/file>' --invert-paths

3 Force push :
git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags

4 Deleting orphaned objects locally:
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive

5 git lfs prune, to clean up unused LFS objects:
git lfs prune


The repository is now purged of large files that were left in the history and no longer exist. The total size of the repository is now 70MB (du -s).
However, the quota on Github has not decreased (Storage == 1.35GB, this corresponds approximately to the size of the large files that no longer exist in the repository, neither in the workspace, nor in the index, nor in the history.
Have I missed something?
I understand that if files exist in the workspace or history, it makes sense for the GitLFS server to keep them. However, in my case, these files have been completely deleted from the repository (including the history) and no longer exist in the .gitattributes file. I was expecting the Git LFS data/quotas on GitHub to decrease as a result. This is not the case! I thought that cleaning up the history would purge the Git LFS server, but it seems that Git LFS keeps the old objects on the server?

How do I write a good title. Your current title differs from the question "the quota on Github has not decreased, Have I missed something?"

having described what I've done, there's normally no trace of large files in my repository and its history. I'm wondering if it's possible to completely delete the old objects tracked by Git LFS. So that's the title of my question, which should normally sum up the whole post, isn't it?

I almost marked your question a duplicate (with How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked), but after re-reading the question it seems different....

@Luuk following your comment, I've edited the title and the post, in the hope that this will make the whole thing clearer!
